# GXT_GWT add listner for checkBox cell Grid

Tags: gwt, checkbox, grid, gxt

My Grid like this
[enter link description here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/GWT/AddCheckBoxtotablecelltodotheeditingExtGWT.htm)

I have a Grid with many checkboxes columns These checkboxes reflect certain properties of my
 data Model(True/False)..How can I add a listener to each checkbox and perform some action upon clicking it? i want to set value for ***listDatas*** when checkBox is selected.. **It is not selectionModel**

I want to set value(true/false) when checkBox is checked... .For example: I have a model( String name, int age, boolean single, boolean indoor, boolean....) Each of boolean is a checkBox column... So i need to change value of model when user click checkBOx --> SO i can change **listDatas** to update database

```
        listStore = new ListStore<DeleteAllTestModel>();

        List<DeleteAllTestModel> listDatas = getDatas();
        listStore.add(listDatas);
        gridView = new PMTGridDeleteAllTest<DeleteAllTestModel>().getPMTGridDeleteAllTest(listStore);
        gridView.setAutoWidth(true);
        gridView.setStripeRows(true);
```

Help Me! Many thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do ... are you just trying to update the boolean values in the database, or are you trying to take an action based upon a change in the checkbox value? If you're just trying to update the value in the database then your `ValueProvider` will do this.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this in GXT you should use GXT `SelectionModel` with `SelectionChangedHandler` or `Selectionhandler`.

Here is two examples how to use it: 
http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:checkboxgrid
http://docs.sencha.com/gxt/3.1.0-beta/ui/grid/SelectionModel.html

Also here is an abstract of an example of my app's grid selection model:

```
List<ColumnConfig<M, ?>> columnsConfigs = new ArrayList<ColumnConfig<M, ?>>();
IdentityValueProvider<M> identityValueProvider = new IdentityValueProvider<M>();
CheckBoxSelectionModel<M> selectColumn = new CheckBoxSelectionModel<M>(identityValueProvider);
selectColumn.setSelectionMode(Style.SelectionMode.MULTI);
columnsConfigs.add(selectColumn.getColumn());
columnsConfigs.addAll(cm.getColumns());
this.cm = new ColumnModel<M>(columnsConfigs);
this.setSelectionModel(selectColumn);
this.getSelectionModel().addSelectionChangedHandler(new SelectionChangedEvent.SelectionChangedHandler<M>() {
    @Override
    public void onSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent<M> event) {
        // TODO whatever you have to do    
    }
});
```

Comment: I want to set value(true/false) when checkBox is checked... .For example: I have a model( String name, int age, boolean single, boolean indoor, boolean....) Each of boolean is a checkBox column... So i need to change value of model when user click checkBOx

Comment: OKay then it is `InlineEditingGrid` or `RowEditingGrid` you need. http://docs.sencha.com/gxt-guides/3/ui/widgets/grid/edit/GridEditing.html

Comment: i can not get back updating listData after editting - > listDatas2 diplays previous data@@
    getListStore().commitChanges();
                listDatas2= getListStore().getModels();